# sending data from multiple threads to main form in C#NET

Tags: multithreading, events, delegates

I have multiple IP devices connected to my computer. Each device is connected using separate thread. Each thread is assigned a function using class instance and communicate using socket programming. all the devices are sending data independently to the PC Software. Now I have to send this data to my main form ( other class) to display.  How to do that ??

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: If you need something more specific, you must update your question and provide more details and perhaps some code.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to pass callback function (from your main form) to the each instance. You may then assign each thread some Id and when calling this callback pass this thread Id along with data so you may differentiate between them.

Comment: Thanks Zoka. I get it done with the use of delegate - event handling.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to have an object that all threads (including the main) know and in which you can put the received data. The main thread/form just needs to read it from time to time. You need to take care of lock/unlock this object before you write/read it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163744.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think in that case i have to monitor my object time to time. Actually I want to send the data to main class at the moment individual threads received it as i have to access database, take some decision and then response back to the IP device. Can i use DELEGATE - EVENT concept here (In case of multithreading ) ?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done this way:

Thread class:
1. declare a delegate --- public delegate void UPDATEVALUE(o_sender, string value);
2. declare a event of delegate type -----  public event UPDATEVALUE update;
3. Raise this event wherever i receive the data ------ update(this, value);

Main class:

1. add the EVENT for each thread that i am creating -- 
   Threadclass tc = new Threadclass();
   tc.update += New Threadclass.UPDATEVALUE(DisplayValue)

where DisplayValue is a Function in MainClass to Display updated value.